# A visualization that can show four different type of data at the same time

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to visualize my data which is as follows:

1. I have 5 different algorithms (alg1, alg2, alg3, alg4, and alg5)
2. I have three groups of users (g1, g2, and g3)
3. For each group, the algorithm is evaluated according to two metrics m1 and m2 (e.g. precision and profit for each group)

I want to visualize all of these in one plot that can show how these algorithms are performing with respect to the two metrics on all three user groups.

I was thinking of a scatter plot but not sure how these all can be incorporated in one scatter plot.

The results for metric m1 are like this: each value has three elements that correspond to three different user groups.

```
{'alg1': [662.0003391054959, 175.32345651614452, 72.03508238727193],
 'alg2': [923.6524005590929, 385.2151039219693, 190.71692280990948],
 'alg3': [1404.387917216172, 446.2766994367938, 213.12994410684388],
 'alg4': [-28.01225225765556, -73.09081443515035, -85.32203386999164],
 'alg5': [1117.9970322350164, 424.7898159256133, 208.7032559089046]}
```

and for metric m2:

```
{'alg1': [0.03111111111111112, 0.04362962962962987, 0.06071428571428592],
 'alg2': [0.0991111111111115, 0.10851851851851772, 0.14776785714285706],
 'alg3': [0.006074074074074077,
  0.02911111111111126,
  0.061904761904762164],
 'alg4': [0.0017777777777777776, 0.00362962962962963, 0.0038690476190476205],
 'alg5': [0.06148148148148173, 0.08140740740740716, 0.12187499999999994]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify algorithms by color and user groups by marker type. M1 and M2 metrics in the axis.

What do you think?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

m1d = {'alg1_m1': [662.0003391054959, 175.32345651614452, 72.03508238727193],
 'alg2_m1': [923.6524005590929, 385.2151039219693, 190.71692280990948],
 'alg3_m1': [1404.387917216172, 446.2766994367938, 213.12994410684388],
 'alg4_m1': [-28.01225225765556, -73.09081443515035, -85.32203386999164],
 'alg5_m1': [1117.9970322350164, 424.7898159256133, 208.7032559089046]}

m2d = {'alg1_m2': [0.03111111111111112, 0.04362962962962987, 0.06071428571428592],
 'alg2_m2': [0.0991111111111115, 0.10851851851851772, 0.14776785714285706],
 'alg3_m2': [0.006074074074074077,
  0.02911111111111126,
  0.061904761904762164],
 'alg4_m2': [0.0017777777777777776, 0.00362962962962963, 0.0038690476190476205],
 'alg5_m2': [0.06148148148148173, 0.08140740740740716, 0.12187499999999994]}

m1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(m1d)
m2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(m2d)

f, ax = plt.subplots()
a = ax.scatter(m1['alg1_m1'],m2['alg1_m2'],color=['r','g','b'], marker='.')
b = ax.scatter(m1['alg2_m1'],m2['alg2_m2'],color=['r','g','b'], marker='v')
c = ax.scatter(m1['alg3_m1'],m2['alg3_m2'],color=['r','g','b'], marker='<')
d = ax.scatter(m1['alg4_m1'],m2['alg4_m2'],color=['r','g','b'], marker='>')
e = ax.scatter(m1['alg5_m1'],m2['alg5_m2'],color=['r','g','b'], marker='^')
ax.set_xlabel('M1')
ax.set_ylabel('M2')

red = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Group 1')
blue = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Group 2')
green = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Group 3')

legend2 = plt.legend(handles=[red, blue, green], loc=1)
plt.legend((a,b,c,d,e),['alg1','alg2','alg3','alg4','alg5'], loc=7)
plt.gca().add_artist(legend2)

leg = ax.get_legend()
for i in range(0,5,1):
    leg.legendHandles[i].set_color('k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get an error for the line `gs = f.add_gridspec(1,1)` indicaring Figure object has no attribute add_gridspec(). I think it is because I use a lower version Anaconda maybe. What does this line do? Do I really need gs ?

Comment: @teoeme139 I'm bookmarking your answer. It's a great toolbox for making custom-symbol legends and multi-legends plots.

Comment: Thanks. This tutorial is great https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html